# RXJava 2.0 deeply nested chain failing to execute parts

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, mockito, rx-java2

I have the following RXJava 2.0 code:

```
private fun <T> wrapApiRequestSingle(apiCall: () -> Single<T>, token: Token) : Single<T> =
        Single.defer {
            apiCall.invoke()
        }.retryWhen { obsError ->
            obsError.flatMap<Single<T>> { error ->
                when (error) {
                    is TokenExpiredException -> {
                        userRepository.getLoggedInUser().toFlowable().flatMap { userOptional ->
                            Publisher<Single<T>> {
                                if (userOptional.isPresent) {
                                    mobileRemote.swapRefreshTokenForAccessToken(token.refreshToken, userOptional.get().emailAddress)
                                            .onErrorResumeNext { refreshError ->
                                                EventReporter.e(TAG, "Failed to refresh JWT.", refreshError)
                                                tokenUseCases.deleteToken().andThen(preferences.singleOrError().flatMap { prefs ->
                                                    prefs.apply {
                                                        this.pushRegistrationId = ""
                                                        this.token = null
                                                    }.apply()

                                                    Single.error<Token>(NoLoggedInUserException())
                                                })
                                            }
                                } else {
                                    EventReporter.e(TAG, "No user was logged in.", error)
                                    tokenUseCases.deleteToken().andThen(preferences.singleOrError().flatMap { prefs ->
                                        prefs.apply {
                                            this.pushRegistrationId = ""
                                            this.token = null
                                        }.apply()

                                        Single.error<Token>(NoLoggedInUserException())
                                    })
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else -> {
                        Flowable.error(error)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The idea being, all API calls will be wrapped by this function. This function has 4 major execution paths:

1. The call succeeds
2. The call fails due to a `TokenExpiredException`, the code falls back to attempting a refresh if, and only if, there is a logged in user. The refresh succeeds and the original call is made again.
3. The call fails due to a `TokenExpiredException`, the code falls back to attempting a refresh if, and only if, there is a logged in user. If the refresh fails then delete some local data and return a `Single` containing a `NoLoggedInUserException`.
4. The call failed and there was no logged in user, so delete some local data and return a `Single` containing a `NoLoggedInUserException`.

The code compiles and I've read the docs for all the functions I'm using, but run time fails to return the `Single.error(NoLoggedInUserException)` for the  4th case.

I decided to write a test case to test the 4th path without needing to hit an actual API or use any actual services. Here is my test code (it uses Mockito to mock out the various sub-systems such as `mobileRemote` and `tokenUseCases`:

```
/**
 * Set of tests to test the main presenter
 */
class ResourceInteractorTests : RobolectricTestBase() {
    @Mock
    private lateinit var injector: InjectorProvider

    @Mock
    private lateinit var preferences: Preferences

    @Mock
    private lateinit var userRepository: UserStorage

    @Mock
    private lateinit var tokenUseCases: TokenUseCases

    @Mock
    private lateinit var mobileRemote: MobileRemote

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        // Initialize all the mocks in this class
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)

        whenever(this.injector.providePreferences()).thenReturn(Observable.just(preferences))
        whenever(this.injector.provideUserStorage()).thenReturn(userRepository)
        whenever(this.injector.provideTokenUseCases()).thenReturn(tokenUseCases)
        whenever(this.injector.provideMobileRemote()).thenReturn(mobileRemote)
    }

    /**
     * Test that getLocations ultimately propagates a [NoLoggedInUserException]
     * When the remote call returns a [TokenExpiredException] and there is no logged in user
     */
    @Test
    fun onGetLocationsFailTokenExpiredNoLoggedInUser() {
        // ARRANGE
        whenever(this.tokenUseCases.getToken()).thenReturn(Single.just(Token("", Date(), "")))
        whenever(this.mobileRemote.getLocations("")).thenReturn(Single.error(TokenExpiredException()))
        whenever(this.userRepository.getLoggedInUser()).thenReturn(Single.just(Optional.absent()))
        whenever(this.tokenUseCases.deleteToken()).thenReturn(Completable.complete())

        val interactor = ResourceInteractor(this.injector)

        // ACT
        val shouldBeError = interactor.getLocations().test()
        shouldBeError.awaitTerminalEvent(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)

        // ASSERT
        shouldBeError.assertError { it is NoLoggedInUserException }
    }
}
```

The idea being that as long as my API call returns a `TokenExpiredException` then the `retryWhen` block will be hit (which it is as I've put breakpoints in my code to verify). The mocked `userRepository` then returns `Optional.absent()` to cause the code under test to enter the else block at the bottom (which it does). Finally, the `tokenUseCases` mock returns `Completable.complete()` for the `deleteTokenOperation` which *should* cause the run time to enter the `andThen` block. However, at run time, the `andThen` block is never reached and the whole chain finishes with no errors. I cannot figure out why this is happening, does anyone have any ideas?

EDIT:

I've been asked, why do I use `Publisher<Single<T>>`, well that is because the `retryWhen` method on the `Single` type requires it:

```
@CheckReturnValue
@SchedulerSupport(SchedulerSupport.NONE)
public final Single<T> retryWhen(Function<? super Flowable<Throwable>, ? extends Publisher<?>> handler) {
    return toSingle(toFlowable().retryWhen(handler));
}
```

Whereas the `Observable` `retryWhen` does not:

```
@CheckReturnValue
@SchedulerSupport(SchedulerSupport.NONE)
public final Observable<T> retryWhen(
final Function<? super Observable<Throwable>, ? extends ObservableSource<?>> handler) {
    ObjectHelper.requireNonNull(handler, "handler is null");
    return RxJavaPlugins.onAssembly(new ObservableRetryWhen<T>(this, handler));
}
```

EDIT 2:

The code under test that invokes the private function wrapApiRequestSingle is here (to clarify the question):

```
override fun getLocations(): Single<Collection<Location>> =
        tokenUseCases.getToken()
                .flatMap { jwt ->
                    wrapApiRequestSingle({
                        mobileRemote.getLocations(jwt.accessToken)
                    }, jwt)
                }
```

EDIT 3:

Took a TDD approach to writing the function by completely starting again and running my test each time I added a new line. Now the function looks like this:

```
private fun <T> wrapApiRequestSingle(apiCall: () -> Single<T>, token: Token) : Single<T> =
        Single.defer {
            apiCall.invoke()
        }.retryWhen { obsError ->
            obsError.flatMap<T> { error ->
                when (error) {
                    is TokenExpiredException -> {
                        userRepository.getLoggedInUser().toFlowable().flatMap { userOptional ->
                            if (userOptional.isPresent) {
                                mobileRemote.swapRefreshTokenForAccessToken(token.refreshToken, userOptional.get().emailAddress).toFlowable()
                                        .onErrorResumeNext {
                                            tokenUseCases.deleteToken().andThen(preferences.toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER).flatMap { prefs ->
                                                prefs.apply {
                                                    this.pushRegistrationId = ""
                                                    this.token = null
                                                }.apply()

                                                Flowable.error<T>(NoLoggedInUserException())
                                            })
                                        }
                            } else {
                                EventReporter.e(TAG, "No user was logged in.", error)
                                tokenUseCases.deleteToken().andThen(
                                        preferences.toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER).flatMap { prefs ->
                                            prefs.apply {
                                                this.pushRegistrationId = ""
                                                this.token = null
                                            }.apply()

                                            Flowable.error<T>(NoLoggedInUserException())
                                        })
                            }
                        }
                    } else -> {
                        Flowable.error<T>(error)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

However, there is a problem with the compiler figuring out how to resolve which overload of onErrorResume next I want to invoke. I've tried explicitly declaring the overload by providing a type on the lambda parameter but the compiler is still complaining about ambiguous type eval.

Comment: Why do you return `Publisher<Single<T>>`? This is higly unusual. You practically tell the `retryWhen` to retry by giving it an object instance. It won't care about what that object is only that it indicates a retry should happen.

Comment: Because the method signature for Single<T>.retryWhen requires it (see my edit on the question)

Comment: In short, this is what you wrote: `source.retryWhen(errors -> errors.flatMap(e -> Flowable.just(Single.error(new NoLoggedInUserException()))))`. You respond to the errors by returning with an object `Single.error(...)` that is not expanded further.

Comment: Could you elaborate further? Are you saying I am returning a Flowable<Single<Exception>> ?

Comment: Just change `obsError.flatMap<Single<T>>` to `obsError.flatMap<T>` and just before the closing curly brace of `is TokenExpiredException -> {`, write `.flatMapSingle { it }`. Also it would be more readable and testable if you pulled out parts of the large statement into its own methods.

Comment: Not asking for my hand to be held, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

From my comment, I meant this:

```
private fun <T> wrapApiRequestSingle(apiCall: () -> Single<T>, token: Token) : Single<T> =
    Single.defer {
        apiCall.invoke()
    }.retryWhen { obsError ->
        obsError.flatMap<T> { error ->    // <---------------------------------------
            when (error) {
                is TokenExpiredException -> {
                    userRepository.getLoggedInUser()
                    .toFlowable()
                    .flatMap { userOptional ->
                        Publisher<Single<T>> {
                            if (userOptional.isPresent) {
                                mobileRemote.swapRefreshTokenForAccessToken(
                                    token.refreshToken, userOptional.get().emailAddress)
                                .onErrorResumeNext { refreshError ->
                                    EventReporter.e(TAG, "Failed to refresh JWT.", refreshError)
                                    tokenUseCases.deleteToken()
                                    .andThen(preferences
                                        .singleOrError()
                                        .flatMap { prefs ->
                                                prefs.apply {
                                                    this.pushRegistrationId = ""
                                                    this.token = null
                                                }.apply()

                                                Single.error<Token>(NoLoggedInUserException())
                                            })
                                        }
                            } else {
                                EventReporter.e(TAG, "No user was logged in.", error)
                                tokenUseCases.deleteToken()
                                .andThen(preferences
                                    .singleOrError()
                                    .flatMap { prefs ->
                                        prefs.apply {
                                            this.pushRegistrationId = ""
                                            this.token = null
                                        }.apply()

                                    Single.error<Token>(NoLoggedInUserException())
                                })
                            }
                        }
                    }.flatMapSingle { it } // <------------------------------------
                }
                else -> {
                    Flowable.error(error)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yea, I did that, it didn't work :-/ 

I'm stripping the function down to a single liner and building it back up, running my test with each iteration to hopefully narrow down where the problem is.

Comment: You have a bunch of logging statement and you can add more to see, along with more logging, where signals stop. Also with mocking based testing you may be mocking the wrong object(s), it is hard to tell from just the code.

Comment: Also it is unclear where you invoke `wrapApiRequestSingle` in your test and what will give it a failing `apiCall`.

Comment: I shall edit the question to show the invoking code. I am definitely mocking all the required dependancies and the mocking is done correctly. You should be able to tell this from the test class.

Comment: Then what remains is placing more logging in the functions and checking which lambdas get executed.

Comment: Yea, I've been doing that for the last 3 hours before I asked the question :D I'm probably just tired and not thinking clearly

Comment: You wrote `deleteToken().andThen()` won't execute. Add `doOnComplete`/`doOnError`/`doOnSubscribe` between them and see if those log something.

Comment: Hey, Akarnokd - I've made some progress by taking a TDD approach, but now I'm hitting a brick wall with ambiguous type eval on Flowable.onErrorResumeNext. I found this link where you mention it may be deprecated:

https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/5303

But the proposed solutions are in Java and I can't see how they apply to Kotlin. I've tried explicitly stating the parameter type to force the compiler to know which overload to use but the ambiguous type eval remains :-(

Comment: I don't know Kotlin that well. Try `.onErrorResumeNext(object: Function<Throwable, Publisher<T>> { /* body here */ })`.